# Getting an attribute from a table row with Selenium | Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find how can I see if this button (image) it's already clicked or not:

[image]

But I haven't been able to do it and I need to interact with this button because it allows me to edit the price of some items and protect them if I don't wan't, the problem is that I need to check if it's clicked or not before doing it.

I have tried many times to identify when it's clicked or not, but I don't see any change on button attributes so I don't know how to do it. I also tried checking on price item and I see one change when it's clicked:

[image]

When it's editable, there is an attribute named "contenteditable" and it's value equals true, but when it's not editable this attribute dissapear and changes for a attribute named "disabled" equals true:

[image]

This are the lines of code that I have been using to get this attribute values:

```
cod = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbodyDatos"]/tr[1]/td[5]/div'))).get_attribute("disabled")

cod = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbodyDatos"]/tr[1]/td[5]/div'))).get_attribute("attributes[1]")

cod = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbodyDatos"]/tr[1]/td[5]/div'))).get_attribute("attributes[1].nodeValue")
```

I would appreciate it so much if anyone can help me.

¡Thanks!

Comment: if it has the class `fa-check-square-o`, it's checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expanded `<i>` along with it's decendants would have possibly given us some hint about some specific attribute to validate if the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) is checked or not.

[image: checkbox]

---

### Solution

You can still probe the if the checkbox is checked or not with respect to the attribute of the adjascent `<div>` attribute as follows:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tbodyDatos"]/tr[1]/td[5]/div'))).click()
    print("Checkbox unchecked")
except (TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException, WebDriverException):
    print("Checkbox checked")
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException, WebDriverException
```

Comment: After I post this question I found how to do it, thank you so much!!